# Named pipe getting "clogged"

Tags: bash, scripts

```
for elem in {1..99} ; do echo $elem> mypipe ; done
```

This piece of bash code should pass 99 ints through the pipe, which previously, in another terminal had this set:

```
cat <mypipe
```

Does anyone know why I'm sometimes only getting a random (less than 99) number of ints passed through the pipe, after which it hangs? I have to terminate the script with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, and I get this message:

```
bash: mypipe: Interrupted system call
```

I am running Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `> mypipe` will open the fifo, write to it, then close it. Once it's closed in either end, you have to reopen it in *both* ends. So instead of reopening the fifo for every echo, keep it open for the entire loop.

```
for elem in {1..99}; do echo "$elem"; done > mypipe
```

Btw, in place of that for loop, you could just use a single printf

```
printf '%s\n' {1..99} > mypipe
```

If you have a more complex case. You can assign an fd to it instead.

```
exec 3> mypipe # opens mypipe for writing on fd 3

echo "stuff" >&3
echo "more stuff" >&3
...

exec 3>&-      # closes fd 3
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/085 for more.